# how to break up data in column value to multiple rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue where I have multiple rows in a csv file that have to be converted to a pandas data frame but there are some rows where the columns 'name' and 'business' have multiple names and businesses that should be in separate rows and need to be split up while keeping the data from the other columns the same for each row that is split.

Here is the example data:

input:

| software | name | business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Andrew Johnson, Steve Martin | Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees,Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees |
| xyz | Jack Jones, Rick Paul, Johnny Jones | Banking, 1001-5000 employees,Construction, 51-200 employees,Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees |
| def | Tom D., Connie J., Ricky B. | Unspecified, Unspecified, Self-employed |

output I need:

| software | name | business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Andrew Johnson | Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees |
| abc | Steve Martin | Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees |
| xyz | Jack Jones | Banking, 1001-5000 employees |
| xyz | Rick Paul | Construction, 51-200 employees |
| xyz | Johnny Jones | Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees |
| def | Tom D | Unspecified |
| def | Connie J | Unspecified |
| def | Ricky B | Self-employed |

There are additional columns similar to 'name' and 'business' that contain multiple pieces of information that need to be split up just like 'name' and 'business'. Cells that contain multiple pieces of information are in sequence (ordered).

Here's the code I have so far and creates new rows but it only splits up the contents in name column, but that leaves the business column and a few other columns left over that need to be split up along with the contents from the name column.

```
name2 = df.name.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df = df.join(pd.Series(index=name2.index.droplevel(1), data=name2.values, name = 'name2'))

dict = df.to_dict('record')
for row in dict:
    new_segment = {}
    new_segment['name'] = str(row['name2'])
    #df['name'] = str(row['name2'])

    for col,content in new_segment.items():
            row[col] = content

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

df = df.drop('name2', 1)
```

Here's an alternative solution I was trying as well but it gives me an error too:

```
review_path = r'data/base_data'
review_files = glob.glob(review_path + "/test_data.csv")

review_df_list = []
for review_file in review_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(review_file), sep = '\t')
    print(df.head())
    df["business"] = (df["business"].str.extractall(r"(?:[\s,]*)(.*?(?:Unspecified|employees|Self-employed))").groupby(level=0).agg(list))
    df["name"] = df["name"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*")
    print(df.explode(["name", "business"]))
    outPutPath = Path('data/base_data/test_data.csv')
    df.to_csv(outPutPath, index=False)
```

Error Message for alternative solution:

Read:data/base_data/review_base.csv

Success!

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [data/base_data/test_data.csv]

Index: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["business"] = (
    df["business"]
    .str.extractall(r"(?:[\s,]*)(.*?(?:Unspecified|employees|Self-employed))")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(list)
)
df["name"] = df["name"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*")

print(df.explode(["name", "business"]))
```

Prints:

```
  software            name                                             business
0      abc  Andrew Johnson            Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees
0      abc    Steve Martin  Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees
1      xyz      Jack Jones                         Banking, 1001-5000 employees
1      xyz       Rick Paul                       Construction, 51-200 employees
1      xyz    Johnny Jones                    Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees
2      def          Tom D.                                          Unspecified
2      def       Connie J.                                          Unspecified
2      def        Ricky B.                                        Self-employed
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include the code you just posted but I still seem to be getting an error message. I have included the error message in my question as well as the updated solution you posted. Would you happen to know why I still get this problem?

Comment: @JackJones Looking at the error, it seems that column `business` is missing? Is there column `business` (case-sensitive) in your CSV?

Comment: Yes the column 'business' does exist and it spelled that way exactly. For some reason I load in the csv file using the code above but when I print the df.head() it comes back empty.